# How to utilize OpenBSD, Nginx, Python and NoSQL

Tags: python, nginx, nosql, openbsd

I'm familiar with LAMP systems and have been programming mostly in PHP for the past 4 years. I'm learning Python and playing around with Nginx a little bit.
We're working on a project website which will handle a lot of http handle requests, stream videos(mostly from a provider like youtube or vimeo). My colleague has experience with OpenBSD and has insisted that we use it as an alternative to linux.

- The reason that we want to use OpenBSD is that it's well known for
  it's security.
- The reason we chose Python is that it's fast.
- The reason we want to use Nginx is that it's known to be able to
  handle more http request when compared to Apache.
- The reason we want to use NoSQL is that MySQL is known to have
  problems in scalability when the databases grows.

We want the web pages to load as fast as possible (caching and cdn's will be used) using the minimum amount of hardware possible. That's why we want to use ONPN (OpenBSD,Nginx,Python,Nosql) instead of the traditional LAMP (Linux,Apache,Mysql,PHP).

We're not a very big company so we're using opensource technologies. Any suggestion is appreciated on how to use these software as a platform and giving hardware suggestions is also appreciated. Any criticism is also welcomed.

Comment: It sounds as though you are making a lot of really hasty, weird design decisions here based on hearsay. I would strongly advise you to reconsider, and/or to evaluate technology yourself before making some choices that you may regret.

Comment: That's why I'm open to suggestions. I had a few problems with Nginx while trying to optimize it with Python. It's not a easy task. I'm thinking about dividing the system to three servers, which each of them will or will not use the ONPN software mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

My advice - if you don't know how to use these technologies - don't do it. Few servers will cost you less than the time spent mastering technologies you don't know. If you want to try them out - do it. One by one, not everything at once. There is no magic solution on how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with wdev, the time it takes to learn this is not worth the money you will save. First of all, MySQL databases are not hard to scale. WordPress utilizes MySQL databases, and some of the world's largest websites use MySQL (google for a list). I can also say the same of linux and PHP.

If you design your site using best practices (CSS sprites) Apache versus Nginx will not make a considerable difference in load times if you utilize a CDN and best practices (caching, gzip, etc).

I strongly urge you to reconsider your decisions. They seem very ill-advised.